# How to bring back 1st div child in python using bs4 soup.select within a dynamic table

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

In the below html elements, I have been unsuccessful using beautiful `soup.select` to only obtain the first child after div class="wrap-25PNPwRV"> (i.e. -11.94M and 2.30M) in list format

```
<div class="value-25PNPwRV">
   <div class="wrap-25PNPwRV">
      <div>‪−11.94M‬</div>
      <div class="change-25PNPwRV negative-25PNPwRV">−119.94%</div></div></div>

<div class="value-25PNPwRV additional-25PNPwRV">
   <div class="wrap-25PNPwRV">
      <div>‪2.30M‬</div>
      <div class="change-25PNPwRV negative-25PNPwRV">−80.17%</div></div></div>
```

Above is just two examples within the html I'm attempting to scrape within the dynamic javascript coded table which the above source code lies within, but there are many more div attributes on the page, and many more div class "wrap-25PNPwRV" inside the javascript table

I currently have the below code which allows me to scrape all the contents within div class ="wrap-25PNPwRV"

```
data_list = [elem.get_text() for elem in soup.select("div.wrap-25PNPwRV")]
```

Output:

```
['-11.94M', '-119.94%', '2.30M', '-80.17%']
```

However, I would like to use `soup.select` to yield the desired output :

```
['-11.94M', '2.30M']
```

I tried following this guide https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ but have been unsuccessful to implement it to my above code.

Please note, if `soup.select` is not possible to perform the above, I am happy to use an alternative providing it generates the same list format/output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector:

```
data_list = [elem.get_text() for elem in soup.select(".wrap-25PNPwRV div:nth-of-type(1)")]
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to not use the `.wrap-25PNPwRV` class. Seems random and almost certainly will change in the future.

Instead, select the `<div>` element which has other element with `class="change..."` as sibling. For example

```py
print([t.text.strip() for t in soup.select('div:has(+ [class^="change"])')])
```

Prints:

```py
['−11.94M', '2.30M']
```

Comment: Thank you for the above suggestion